# Parameters of combo box change event in ext js

Tags: extjs

Which parameters i should pass in combo box select event in ext js?

Answer (score 3):

Quoted from [ExtJS 3.3.1 API Documentation](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.ComboBox):

```
select: (Ext.form.ComboBox combo, Ext.data.Record record, Number index)
```

Fires when a list item is selected. Listeners will be called with the following arguments:

- `combo : Ext.form.ComboBox` -
    This combo box
- `record : Ext.data.Record` -
    The data record returned from the underlying store
- `index : Number` -
    The index of the selected item in the dropdown list

Comment: I have been looking for this.  That link redirects to sencha.com and is broken.  For anyone with 3.3.1 legacy code, go to  [http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.3.1/docs/](http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.3.1/docs/) and click on `Ext` in the left nav menu.